# To display the selected part in line of text file

Tags: grep

I have the following in a text file:

```
0400903071220312  20120322 20:21
1TRANTELSTRAFLEXCAB22032012CMP201323930000812201108875802100A003485363          12122011AUS          182644             000C28122011        0000                     000
```

How can I pull just the `3071` out of the first line?

Comment: It depends on why 3071 is special. Is it because of its position, or because it is exactly the value 3071, or because of what comes before or after it, etc?

Answer (score 2):

You don't say how you want to determine what's displayed, but `-o` shows only the matched expression, so `grep -o 3071 file` would just display the 3071.

Comment: I vote for `echo 3071` at that point

Answer (score 1):

To get the data from this position in a text file, you could use a tiny awk-script

```
awk '{print substr($0,7,4); exit;}' yourfilename
```

or work with *head* and *cut*

```
head -1 yourfilename | cut -c7-10
```